# Can't add android library to JCenter

Tags: android, lib, bintray, jcenter

I am trying to publish the library to JCenter with Bintray, according to this article: https://medium.com/@anitaa_1990/6-easy-steps-to-upload-your-android-library-to-bintray-jcenter-59e6030c8890.

I successfully added the library to `Bintray`, but when I click on "**Add to JCenter**" button and send compose message - I am getting an **error**:

> Failed to send a message: Package should include sources as part of the package.

Please, tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your Bintray repository?

Comment: Sure @Royg, https://bintray.com/itcherry/KotlinRxSocket/kotlinrxsocket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Bintray Maven Package doesn't contain the `sources`, only `.aar` and the `.pom`. The in the [blog post](https://medium.com/@anitaa_1990/6-easy-steps-to-upload-your-android-library-to-bintray-jcenter-59e6030c8890) isn't linked to JCenter, see blog's [package here](https://bintray.com/murthyanitaa/Optimize/optimize).

Bintray's [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Central+Repositories#_jcenter) states that you have to include the `sources`.

**I would use this [blog post](https://medium.com/@yegor_zatsepin/simple-way-to-publish-your-android-library-to-jcenter-d1e145bacf13) or [this one](https://medium.com/@daniellevass/how-to-publish-your-android-studio-library-to-jcenter-5384172c4739)**, where the packages are actually linked to JCenter.

Answer (score 0):

For developers who reach here today, make sure your configuration file has `artifact(sourcesJar.get())` in `publishing{}` like these lines below (not complete `build.gradle.kts`).

```
val sourcesJar by tasks.registering(Jar::class) {
    classifier = "sources"
    from(sourceSets.main.get().allSource)
}

publishing {
  publications {
    create<MavenPublication>("default") {
      from(components["java"])
        artifact(dokkaJar)
    }
  }

  publications.invoke {
    publicationName(MavenPublication::class) {
      artifactId = artifactID
      artifact(sourcesJar.get()) // This line
    }
  }
}
```